# Is a Covering Space of a Topological Space always Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Is a Covering Space of a Topological Space always Hausdorff?

I can separate two different points from the same fiber, but what about two arbitrary points?

Comment: Every topological space is a covering of itself, but there are non-Hausdorff spaces. Thus, the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A covering space of a *Hausdorff* space is always Hausdorff. Either you can separate points in the base and take preimages, or you can use your proof if the points lie in the same fiber.